# Number of intersections

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a real valued function  so that $$| f(x) - f(y)|  \leq \frac 12 |x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then find the number of intersections of the grafh $f(x)$ with the line $y= x$.
>
> *The answer  should be $1$.*

First I prove the function to be continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ by taking $\lim x\to y$ in both sides of the inequality.

It gives $f(x) \to f(y)$ for a particular $y$ so it is continuous  at $y$.

But then I can't approach. So any hint of the problem.

Comment: It's helpful for reads if you format your question using $\LaTeX$. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The function is continuous but how does that help with the number of intersection points? Have you thought of the significance of $1/2$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f$ will intersect the line iff $f(x) = x$, i.e., iff $x$ is a fixed point of $f$ (this is the key of the problem) That's my hint, so don't continue reading if you want to try it yourself. Because of this, it suffices to show that there is only one fixed point of $f$. This becomes easy by the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). However, if you want to prove it explicitly, you can adapt the demonstration of the theorem to your problem.

- The unicity is obvious: if $x_1$, $x_2$ where both different fixed points, your must have $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = |x_1 - x_2|$, but this is a contradiction with the hypothesis $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 1/2|x - y|$.
- For the existence:

If we define the sequence $x_j = f^j(x)$ (this means to apply $j$ times $f$ to $x$), it is a Cauchy one:
\begin{equation}
|x_m - x_n| \leq \sum_{j=n}^{m-1}|x_{x+1} - x_j| \leq \left(\sum_{j=n}^{m-1}(1/2)^j\right)|x_1 - x_0| \leq \left(\sum_{j\geq n}(1/2)^j\right)|x_1 - x_0| = \frac{(1/2)^j}{1 - 1/2}|x_1 - x_0|
\end{equation}
The right part converges to $0$ (notice that it's the tail of a convergent serie), so $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then, by the completeness of $R$, a Cauchy sequence is also a convergent sequence and, finally, denoting $x_\ast :=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}
|f(x_\ast) - x_\ast| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n) - x_n| = \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{x+1} - x_n| = 0,
\end{equation}
so $x_\ast$ is a fixed point of $f$.